# Depth First Search on a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm

I have the following implementation of a Depth First Search algorithm:

```
 public static void printDFS(Node root) {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

        stack.push(root);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Node curr = stack.pop();
            System.out.println(curr.getValue())      ;
            if (curr.getLeft() != null) {
                stack.push(curr.getLeft());
            }
            if (curr.getRight() != null) {
                stack.push(curr.getRight());
            }
        }
    }
```

and when I run it on a tree that looks like this:

```
                        0
                      /   \
                     6     7
                    / \   / \
                   5   4 3   2
```

I get the visited output as: 0 -> 7 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6 -> 4 -> 5

Is this a 'correct' DFS ordering? I would have expected the output to have been a pre-order traversal (ie 0 ->6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 3 -> 2) and I know I can get this by first pushing the right node of each subtree. But what I want to know is what is the *correct* visitation order in a DFS algorithm?

Comment: I believe you'll get the order you expected by pushing the right node before left, thus popping off left before right when you actually process the nodes.

Comment: Both are correct visitation orders of DFS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967725/1803692) the reason why your visitation -> traversal order is "inversed" lies in the fact that you are using a Stack to keep track of the "current node".

Let me walk you through your example tree:

```
                    0 
                  /   \
                 6     7
                / \   / \
               5   4 3   2
```

`stack.push(root)` leads to following stack state:

```
0: 0 <-- (root) and Top of stack
```

You're popping the stack and put it in `curr`. In traversal terms you are now in this state:

```
                    0 <--
                  /   \
                 6     7
                / \   / \
               5   4 3   2
```

you then proceed to add `curr.getLeft()` to the stack and then `curr.getRight()`. This leads to following stack state:

```
1: 7 <--(curr.getRight()) <-- Top of stack
0: 6 <--(curr.getLeft())
```

Repeating the same step we get following traversal state:

```
                    0 
                  /   \
                 6     7<--
                / \   / \
               5   4 3   2
```

and after adding the nodes:

```
2: 2 <-- Top of stack
1: 3
0: 6 <-- (initial getLeft())
```

as both nodes have no children, popping them from the stack and outputting them gets us to following traversal state:

```
                    0 
                  /   \
              -->6     7
                / \   / \
               5   4 3   2
```

The rest of this is history ;)

As you specificially asked about a "correct" way (or ordering) for a DFS: There is none. You define what side you traverse to depth first.

Answer (score 2):

It's a stack. What you push last will pop first

Comment: While this is the correct cause for the difference between expected and actual output it would probably be helpful to OP if you could explain a little more...p

Answer (score 2):

There is no such *"correct DFS ordering"*. The main idea of DFS is to go *deep*; visiting children before siblings for any given node. Once you go far deep in the graph and you encounter a leaf, you *backtrack* and examine the nearest sibling in the same way.

The way you choose which child to examine first result in different traversing orders (or trees). Needless to say, all traversing methods result in a spanning tree over the graph. Pre-order traversing, the one you are comparing with, is probably the most well known order for DFS (or at least this is what I have seen). Others are valid but not *too* popular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code for DFS:

'''
This is much more of a traversal algorithm than search.
'''

```
Algorithm DFS(Tree):
     initialize stack to contain Tree.root()
     while stack is not empty:
         p = stack.pop()
         perform 'action' for p
         for each child 'c' in Tree.children(p):
             stack.push(c)
```

This will search through all the nodes of tree whether binary or not.
To implement search and return.. modify the algorithm accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

There are a few options to consider for your  DFS algorithm:

1. Firstly, use `Backtracking` algorithm to do a DFS search.
2. If using `Backtracking` add only `leftChild` while traversing downwards. Otherwise reverse the order in which you `push()` node's children onto the `Stack` i.e `rightChild` right and then `leftChild`.
3. Again if using `Backtracking`, avoid cycles by creating a variable `nodeVistited` which will be set to true once a node has been pushed on stack. Not needed otherwise.
   Try with these changes or let me know I will post code for DFS.

Comment: The example traversals and their outputs from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on DFS contradict your first point. You're hanging yourself up on minor implementation details. Additionally your second point is blatantly incorrect and the  third point is irrelevant. Already visited nodes are tracked in the stack. In a clean tree (as it is assumed) no nodes will be revisited

Comment: @Vogel612 For point 1. I would say DFS is a  `Backtracking` algorithm and hence its algorithm should be based on the same. Which maintains a stack of all nodes from `root` to `leaf` node. As for Point 2. In order to achieve the traversal order mentioned by user he has two options. First I already mentioned i.e to add only `leftChild` while traversing down the tree. Second option is to reverse the order of pushing `leftChild` and `rightChild` onto the stack i.e `rightChild` first and then `leftChild`. Point 3. is optional as per design. My answer is as per question asked not as per wikipedia.

Comment: Backtracking does not require to maintain **all** nodes from `root` to `leaf`, just those that were not "completed" yet. OP's code already accomplishes that, and the point you are making in 1. does not address that in any way. concerning 2.: "at the same time" is incorrect. one after another is **not** at the same time. Also DFS or BFS only depends on how you handle stuff. It would be easy to switch this from a DFS to a BFS traversal by changing the `Stack` to a `Queue`. While your answer relates to the question it's .. wrong ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 without all the elements from `root` to `leaf` node, backtracking to root is not possible. `at the same time` means a traversal step not in the context of time. thought you be smart enough to understand that ;).

Comment: The 'Backtracking' you describe is an implementation detail. A DFS does not require Backtracking for correct execution, this means your initial assumption is "incorrect". There is no necessity to backtrack to root for a DFS. I would say "at the same time" is pretty... unambiguous, I'd probably not have criticised "in the same traversal step". I would be interested in how you'd solve the problem without somewhen adding both children of a Node to the backtracking queue ;) Btw, feel free to join me in [chat] for a discussion. You can find me in the Java room

Comment: @Vogel612 I will add and examine `rightChild` when traversing up the the tree i.e once complete left branch has been examined. feel like going in circles.